# PHP Fatal error on CI/CD run php artisan test

Tags: laravel, docker, unit-testing, cicd

I use `docker-compose` with laravel and `postgresql` and all works fine in local system. The problem is in the CI/CD.

I have changed the CI/CD yml file over and over but I am stuck!

##### CI/CD

```yaml
name: CI/CD

on:
  pull_request:
    branches: ['master']
  push:
    branches: ['master']

jobs:
  test:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - uses: shivammathur/setup-php@v2
        with:
          php-version: '7.4'
      - uses: actions/checkout@v2

      - name: Run Containers
        run: docker-compose -f docker-compose.yml -f docker-compose.dev.yml up -d

      # - name: Run composer install
      #   run: cd companyname_app_dir && composer install

      # - name: Run composer update
      #   run: cd companyname_app_dir&& composer update

      # - name: Setup Project
      #   run: |
      #     cd companyname_app_dir
      #     composer update
      #     composer install
      #     php artisan config:clear
      #     php artisan cache:clear

      - name: Run test
        run: cd companyname_app_dir && php artisan test
        env:
          APP_KEY: base64:x06N/IsV5iJ+R6TKlr6sC6Mr4riGgl8Rg09XHHnRZQw=
          APP_ENV: testing
          DB_CONNECTION: companyname-postgres
          DB_DATABASE: db_test
          DB_USERNAME: root
          DB_PASSWORD: 1234

  deploy:
    needs: test
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: Set up QEMU
        uses: docker/setup-qemu-action@v2

      - name: Set up Docker Buildx
        uses: docker/setup-buildx-action@v2

      - name: Login to Docker Hub
        uses: docker/login-action@v2
        with:
          username: secret
          password: secret

      - name: Build and push
        uses: docker/build-push-action@v3
        with:
          push: true
          file: ./companyname_app_dir/Dockerfile
          tags: company_image:latest
          build-args: |
            "NODE_ENV=production"
```

There are line comments, I tried using these but I couldn't run a test successfully.

##### docker-compose

```yaml
version: '3'

networks:
  companyname_network:
    driver: bridge

services:
  nginx:
    image: nginx:stable-alpine
    container_name: companyname-nginx
    volumes:
      - ./nginx/default.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf:ro
    restart: always
    depends_on:
      - companyname_app
    networks:
      - companyname_network

  companyname_app:
    restart: 'always'
    image: 'companyname_laravel'
    container_name: companyname-app
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: ./Dockerfile
    networks:
      - companyname_network
    depends_on:
      - companyname_db

  companyname_db:
    image: 'companyname_multiple_db'
    container_name: companyname-postgres
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: ./DockerfileDB
    restart: 'always'
    volumes:
      - local_pgdata:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_MULTIPLE_DATABASES=db,db_test
      - POSTGRES_USER=root
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=1234
    ports:
      - 15432:5432
    networks:
      - companyname_network

  companyname_dbadmin:
    image: adminer
    container_name: companyname-dbadmin
    restart: 'always'
    depends_on:
      - companyname_db
    ports:
      - 5051:8080
    networks:
      - companyname_network

volumes:
  local_pgdata:
```

##### docker-compose.dev

```yaml
version: '3'

services:
  nginx:
    ports:
      - 9000:80

  companyname_app:
    build: 
      args:
        - NODE_ENV=development
    volumes:
      - ./companyname_app_dir:/app
      - /app/vendor
```

With this file, I get an error:

> Run cd companyname_app_dir && php artisan test
> PHP Warning:  require(/home/runner/work/companyname_app/companyname_app /companyname_app_dir/vendor/autoload.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/runner/work/companyname_app/companyname_app/companyname_app_dir/artisan on line 18
> PHP Fatal error:  require(): Failed opening required '/home/runner/work/companyname_app/companyname_app/companyname_app_dir/vendor/autoload.php' (include_path='.:/usr/share/php') in /home/runner/work/companyname_app/companyname_app/companyname_app_dir/artisan on line 18
> Error: Process completed with exit code 255.

if I use:

```yaml
- name: Run composer install
  run: cd companyname_app_dir && composer install

- name: Run composer update
  run: cd companyname_app_dir && composer update
```

In CI/CD yml and remove `Run Containers` part, `composer install` and `update` successfully, but `php artisan test` throws this error:

> postgresql can not connect

Answer (score 1):

1. You must use `composer install`, else you will have no `vendor` folder at all, so you have nothing to run. That is why you are getting an error if you don't run `composer install`
2. You should not run `composer update`, because you are updating packages to new versions, you never do that in production, you just run `composer install --no-dev`
3. You are mixing running docker with a command OUTSIDE the docker container.

Related to point `3.`, if you are using `docker-compose`, you cannot execute:

```yaml
- name: Run test
  run: cd companyname_app_dir && php artisan test
  env:
    APP_KEY: base64:x06N/IsV5iJ+R6TKlr6sC6Mr4riGgl8Rg09XHHnRZQw=
    APP_ENV: testing
    DB_CONNECTION: companyname-postgres
    DB_DATABASE: db_test
    DB_USERNAME: root
    DB_PASSWORD: 1234
```

Because you are outside `docker`, so you should execute `docker-compose exec companyname_app php artisan test`, that will execute the tests INSIDE the docker container, where you correctly have everything setup.

So your code (if I am not missing anything) should be:

```yaml
- name: Run test
  run: docker-compose exec companyname_app php artisan test
  env:
    APP_KEY: base64:x06N/IsV5iJ+R6TKlr6sC6Mr4riGgl8Rg09XHHnRZQw=
    APP_ENV: testing
    DB_CONNECTION: companyname-postgres
    DB_DATABASE: db_test
    DB_USERNAME: root
    DB_PASSWORD: 1234
```

But I am not certaing what will you get back from that execution, I have no idea if the test fails, if the CI/CD (I am assuming you are using GitHub Actions or Bitbucket Pipelines), will truly identify that it has failed or not.

---

What I usually do, is just install everything on the machine (CI/CD machine), instead of using a docker file or docker-compose yaml. But that is my preference (at least for PHP/Laravel)

Comment: Thank you so much for your explanation and good edit to question.
I get it why I couldn't execute Run test.
I use GitHub Actions.
I changed my CI/CD with your code, but I get this error :
```Error: Process completed with exit code 1.
```. Also I add step `Run composer install` and still I get this error.
my code:
```- name: Run Test
  run: docker-compose exec vira_app php artisan test```
or
```- name: Run Test
  run: docker-compose -f docker-compose.yml -f docker-compose.dev.yml exec vira_app php artisan test```

Comment: I found https://gist.github.com/JustinByrne/a81653d939c1221cd2d6a03f39757179this and it solved my problem.